# How to get Property Transfer in SoapUI testcase to work?

Tags: xpath, soapui

I'm trying to transfer a value from the response of one WS call to the request of another using SoapUI's Transfer Property TestStep.

First WS response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns5:PSResponse xmlns:ns5="http://www.ab.com/abonline/service/PaymentService/1.0/" xmlns:ns6="http://www.ab.com/abonline/service/CustomerCard/1.0/" xmlns:ns7="https://secure.incab.se/DTServerModuleService/v1">
      <ns5:abTransactionReference>1085-0</ns5:abTransactionReference>
      <ns5:status>0</ns5:status>
    </ns5:PSResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Parsing the property works fine using an expression like:
`declare namespace ns5="http://www.ab.com/abnline/service/PaymentService/1.0/"
//ns5:abTransactionReference`

The next request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://www.ab.com/abonline/service/PaymentService/1.0/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <UpdatePaymentRequest>
      <abTransactionReference>30</abTransactionReference>
... ...
```

I try inserting the property into the next request using:
`//abTransactionReference`

Gives me: `[Missing match for Target XPath [//abTransactionReference]]`

I also tried a full xpath:
`declare namespace soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/UpdatePaymentRequest/abTransactionReference`

...resulting in similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you should set the default namespace to `http://www.ab.com/...` as well

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `""` for the namespace definition.  For example, in the case above >>

```
declare namespace soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
```

should be

```
declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add XPath Assertions to UpdatePaymentRequest request message. Click on the Declare button on the XPath Match Configuration dialog and you will see what prefix soapUI uses for 'http://www.ab.com/abonline/service/PaymentService/1.0/' namespace. I think it will be like:

```
declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='http://www.ab.com/abonline/service/PaymentService/1.0/';
```

(see http://testautomationnoob.blogspot.com.by/2013/12/xpath-in-soapui-part-1-xpath-assertions.html). Then there is no need to have XPath Assertions - you can remove it. So, use "ns1" prefix in your xpath. In the end you will have the following xpath:

```
declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='http://www.ab.com/abonline/service/PaymentService/1.0/';
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns1:UpdatePaymentRequest/ns1:abTransactionReference
```

Comment: link-only answers are not the way of SO. Please elaborate your answer.